# Reusable lazy loading with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

Here are some methods I have in my `UserRepository` class :

```
// Get a user with all his roles
getWithRoles(Long userId);

// Get a user with all his posts
getWithPosts(Long userId);

// Get a user with all his activities
getWithActivities(Long userId);

// Get a user with all his relations
getWithAllRelations(Long userId);
```

These methods all have something like bellow to determine the relations to be loaded:

```
// An example for getWithRoles(Long userId);
criteria.setFetchMode("roles", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

I did my best to not duplicate codes between these methods but it is still hard to maintain IMO.

Is there a way to avoid this and end up with something like bellow?

```
userRepo.findOne(userId)
        .withRelation(User_.roles)
        .withRelation(User_.posts);

userRepo.findOne(userId)
        .withRelation(User_.roles)
        .withRelation(User_.activities);

userRepo.findOne(userId)
        .withAllRelations();
```

I'm basically looking for a way to reuse relations-fetcher methods without rewriting a whole new method just for that.

PS: In the example above, `User_` is a [JPA Static Metamodel](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html)

Comment: What type is `userRepo`?

Comment: userRepo is a simple JPA Repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found an idea to implement this in the repository.

I just need to pass a list of attributes as a second argument.

```
get(Long userId, List<String> relations);
```

Or even better

```
get(Long userId, List<Attribute> relations);
```

The implementation of this will loop through the relations argument, and fetch them one by one.

The difficult part is when I have to deal with nested relations.